# How to listen to a var with google translate

Tags: javascript, html

We are using HTML5/Javascrpt.

Lets say we have a list with every player's name from Barcelona (for example name = 'Lionel Messi'). I want to listen to the player's name. In order to do that i would use:

var narrator = new Audio('https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&tl=tr-TR&client=tw-ob&q=The+players+name+is' + name);
narrator.play();

This would work if the variable name was equal to 'Lionel+Messi'. But now it is equal to 'Lionel Messi' and we cannot change the value of name.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you just asking how to URL-encode a string value?

Answer (score 0):

You probably just want to use `encodeURIComponent`:

```
var narrator = new Audio('https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&tl=tr-TR&client=tw-ob&q=The+players+name+is' + encodeURIComponent(name)); narrator.play();
```

Comment: That was close. But this adds "%20" between every word. So we will get 'Lionel%20Messi', but what we want to get is 'Lionel+Messi'. That is how google translate works. Is there anything like that? Anything that adds the symbol "+" between words? Thank you.

Comment: `name.split(' ').join('+')`

Comment: It also works with `%20` in place of `+`, check [here](https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&tl=tr-TR&client=tw-ob&q=The+players+name+is+Lionel%20Messi)